# Illegal value used for attribute name during xslt Transformation in java

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xalan

Hi I'm trying to transform an XML to another XML using xsl. The XSL transformation is working fine when tested in Oxygen developer and in VM also.

But still I'm getting an Warning like "Illegal value used for attribute name" at line number 20 and 23.

XSL which i used is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:cl="http://tyryt.com/abc/abc_order"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:java="http://xml.apache.org/xslt/java"
        exclude-result-prefixes="cl xsd java" version="1.0">
        <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>

        <xsl:template name="generateInsightsHeader">
            <xsl:for-each select="/">
                <xsl:element name="pon">
                    <xsl:value-of select="*/cl:HDR/cl:PON"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="version">
                    <xsl:value-of select="*/cl:HDR/cl:VER"/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template name="copyWholeXml" match="*">
            <xsl:if test="local-name() != 'brmserrorxml'">
                <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
                    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                        <xsl:if test="../@protocoltype != ''">
                            <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="/">
            <IntermediateXml xmlns:json="http://json.org/">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="cl:SAMPLE_ORDER">
                        <xsl:call-template name="generateInsightsHeader"/>
                        <xsl:call-template name="copyWholeXml"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </IntermediateXml>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

and Sample XML i used is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <SAMPLE_ORDER class="1" index="0" xmlns="http://tyryt.com/abc/abc_order" service="SAMPLE_ORDER">
      <header>
        <interfaceid>INTERFACE_REQUIRED</interfaceid>
        <actionrequired>Transmit</actionrequired>
      </header>
      <HDR>
        <MESSAGE_ID>229364ASE</MESSAGE_ID>
        <DATE>2017-09-04T12:29:11+05:30</DATE>
        <PON>229364ASE10</PON>
        <VER>01</VER>
      </HDR>
      <LOCAL_MESSAGE>
        <LOCAL_ADMIN>
          <LOCQTY>111</LOCQTY>
          <AN>JHGKJ679868</AN>
          <CC>005F</CC>
          <AUTHORIZATION>
            <DDD>20171228</DDD>
            <ACTL>01234567899</ACTL>
          </AUTHORIZATION>
        </LOCAL_ADMIN>
        <LSR_BILL>
          <ACNA>WEE</ACNA>
        </LSR_BILL>
        <CONTACT>
          <INIT>ASDDFAD</INIT>
          <INIT_TEL_NO>2543654576</INIT_TEL_NO>
          <INIT_EMAIL>abc@gmail.com</INIT_EMAIL>
        </CONTACT>
      </LOCAL_MESSAGE>
      <LS>
        <LS_SVC_DET>
          <SVC_DET_GRP>
            <LOCNUM>145</LOCNUM>
            <LNUM>78945</LNUM>
            <LNA>D</LNA>
            <ECCKT>98698KJGKUJGUKJH</ECCKT>
          </SVC_DET_GRP>
        </LS_SVC_DET>
      </LS>
    </SAMPLE_ORDER>
```

For Transformation i'm using Xalan jar.

Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: So which lines are those 20 and 23? Please show them separately in addition to the full code.

Comment: please add your expected output.

Comment: @Joel M. Lamsen expected output is as follows.........
<IntermediateXml xmlns:json="http://json.org/"><pon>229364ASE10</pon><version>01</version><SAMPLE_ORDER><header>        <interfaceid>INTERFACE_REQUIRED</interfaceid>        ......      </header>      <HDR>       <MESSAGE_ID>229364ASE</MESSAGE_ID>        <DATE>2017-09-04T12:29:11+05:30</DATE>        <PON>229364ASE10</PON>        <VER>01</VER>      </HDR>      <LOCAL_MESSAGE>        <LOCAL_ADMIN>         <LOCQTY>111</LOCQTY>          .....        </LOCAL_ADMIN>        ......    </SAMPLE_ORDER></IntermediateXml>

Comment: Please edit your question and place there your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

The root node has no name, or more precisely, the name of the document's root node is the empty string ''. So when you call your template "copyWholeXml" and the current context node is the root node, `local-name()` evaluates to '', and `<xsl:element name="{local-name()}">` is invalid, because you cannot generate a new XML element with an empty string as the name.
When you call your template "copyWholeXml" make sure that you are not entering the named template with the document root as the context node